# What is the relation between network interface card(NIC) and Open street map files and Results of VANETs Scenarios in OMNET Simulator,Veins,Sumo?

Tags: wifi, omnet++, nic, scenarios

I want to ask whether if Ethernet port as hardware (Cable) is disabled in my Laptop (Dell) and I have updated all Network adapters with WLAN adapters in my laptop and they are all working properly
I have executed VANETs Scenarios on OMNET++ Simulator . the resuls that I will get are correct or not ?  as you know that We extract open street map files from gatcomsumo that belong to nic (Physical layer,Link layer)
please there is attached image of all Network Interface Cards in my laptop in the below link .

[Network Interface Cards(NIC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meEir.jpg)